# how to update a value in my data list in nestjs (It will look at the arrays in the list and find the value to be updated there)

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, nest

```
 {
      "_id": "8756e86d6822192a163f07a3",
        "user": "yy@hotmail.com",
        "city": "city4",
        "AddressLine2": "addr 4",
    }    
    {
      "_id": "6256e86d6822192a163f07a3",
        "billingAddr": "true",
        "user": "yy@hotmail.com",
        "city": "city",
        "AddressLine2": "addr 2",
    }
    {  "_id": "6256e86grttrga163f07a3",
        "user": "xx@hotmail.com",
        "city": "city2",
        "AddressLine2": "addr 3",
    }
```

I want it to find the data where the "billingAddr" value is and update it to false.

address.service.ts

```
constructor(
    @InjectModel('Address') private addrModel: Model<AddressDocument>,
) { }
async findAll(): Promise<Address[]> {
    return this.addrModel.find().exec();
}
```

address.controller.ts

```
constructor(private addrService: AddressService) { }
@Get('/all')
async findAllList() {
    return this.addrService.findAll();
}
```

How can I find the billingAddr value and update it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not Angular and this is basic usage of NestJS. You should do a little research on your own, but since I need some reputation ...

```
updateBilling() { 
  return this.addrModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { billingAddr: "true" }, 
    { billingAddr: "false" })
  .exec();
}
```

Also for what it's worth, this is totally not the way to do it. You'll figure that out on your own along the road later on.

Also x2, use a boolean instead of a string equal to "true" or "false".

Comment: I know it's not angular, I'm writing nest, I already wrote it for an idea, methods similar to angular :)   @temp_user actually what i want to do is complicated so i couldn't explain all of them. I have an address list, the billing address is true, if the button is active. but if I enter another address value and mark the billing address as true on it, the old one should be false. 
i hope i can explain

Comment: I'm telling you it's not angular because you used the tag angular, that's all. And for your goal, I'll let you just go ahead and see why it does not do what you want, this is part of the learning process after all !

Comment: @oykn removing the accepted label without giving an explanation ? Why ?

Comment: I'm trying to write it this way and get it with @Get , but no address is coming.